# is it safe to convert p12 to pem in a public website?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i want to convert p12 key to pem to use it in a Push notification service for iphone.

i found a website that do that for free (https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html)

**my question is:**

**is it safe to use a public website to do this conversation, or it may cause some issue as this website can access my iphone application and send notification for my users?**

Comment: Is it safe to hand your house key over to some random stranger on the street for duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your private key is private. By sending the private key to a 3rd party, the 3rd party can identify themselves as you. They won't be able to get a certificate for it without the username and password for the Apple ID that has access to the provisioning portal. But if they in some way get a hold of your certificate, and they already have your private key, they have full control. So in a way it becomes a question of whether or not you trust sslshopper.com to not abuse your private key.

The openssl CLI has all the tools you need to convert keypairs and certs from and to all kinds of formats, in a trusted (1st party) environment.